# Stop text from wrapping underneath image

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I want to stop the text from wrapping underneath an image, **without making any changes to the HTML.** Can this be done solely by CSS? I know the text can be wrapped in a div but I'm not able to do that on Wordpress.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s01x1ere/

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="amazon.com"><img src="https://www.easycalculation.com/area/images/big-square.gif"></a>
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
  </p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width:500px;
}

img {
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the above answer or you can just update your jsfiddle css with below css.

```
div {
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:100px;
}

img {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the div, set `margin-bottom` of the image to the height minus the image's height.

For example, if the height of the div is 500px and the height of the image is 100px, then use `margin-bottom: 400px`.

```
img {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please attache this code

```css
div { width:500px; }
img { float:left; height:100px; width:100px; margin-right: 15px;}
p { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div>
            <p>
              <a href="amazon.com"><img src="https://www.easycalculation.com/area/images/big-square.gif"></a>
              Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
            </p>
        </div>
```